# Session data lost on Woocommerce ajax call

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm working on a Woocommerce plugin that add some vars in session on "add to cart" action, and use those vars later when order is completed and for the order confirmation email.

Basically the workflow is the following:

1. On **`woocommerce_add_to_cart`** action, set those session vars.

   ```
   add_filter('woocommerce_add_to_cart', array(&$this->wc, 'add_to_cart'), 10, 1);
   ```

   ```
   public function add_to_cart($cart_item_key) {
       if(!isset($_SESSION['tickets'])) {
           $_SESSION['tickets'] = array();
       }
       $_SESSION['tickets'][$cart_item_key] = array();
       foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
           if(preg_match('#^ticket_#', $key)) {
               $_SESSION['tickets'][$cart_item_key][$key] = $value;
           }
       }
   }
   ```
2. On **`woocommerce_email_after_order_table`**, use those vars to add informations into the confirmation email.

   ```
   add_action('woocommerce_email_after_order_table', array(&$this->wc, 'email_after_order_table'), 10, 1);
   ```

   ```
   public function email_after_order_table($order) {
       if(isset($_SESSION['tickets']) && !empty($_SESSION['tickets'])) {
           $output = '';
           foreach($_SESSION['tickets'] as $cart_item) {
               if(is_array($cart_item) && !empty($cart_item)) {
                   foreach($cart_item as $ticket_id) {
                       $ticket = get_post($ticket_id);
                       $room = get_the_term_list($ticket_id, 'product_tag');
                       $output .= $ticket->post_title . ' (' . $room . ')<br />';
                   }
               }
           }
           if(!empty($output)) {
               echo '<h4>' . __('Tickets', 'my-context') . '</h4><p>' . $output . '</p>';
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   Please note that this action is executed by Woocommerce on the `?wc-ajax=checkout` ajax call.
3. On **`woocommerce_order_status_completed`** or **`woocommerce_order_status_on-hold`**, update some CPT using those vars, then delete the session vars.

The problem I have is that when hooking on **`woocommerce_email_after_order_table`**  `$_SESSION` is empty. If I look on `$_COOKIE['PHPSESSID']`, it is set and as the same value as in the context where those session vars are set. And if I try to query the CPT, they aren't updated yet, so the **`woocommerce_order_status_completed`** hook (which is working and have no issue accessing the session vars) isn't yet executed.

I tried using [`WC_Session`](https://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Session.html) instead of `$_SESSION`, it didn't changed anything (step 1 and 3 were working but not step 2).

Does anyone know why the **`woocommerce_email_after_order_table`** action isn't in the same context as **`woocommerce_order_status_completed`**? Is there any way to pass custom data in that hook?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Allright I found out what was going on by tracking the hooks execution time, and figured that the `woocommerce_order_status_complete`  was executed slightly before the email hooks. It seems Woocommerce doesn't provide any hook in fact that is executed ***after*** all order actions have been processed.

```
woocommerce_order_status_complete           0.15321100 1453995747
woocommerce_email_after_order_table         0.40655700 1453995747
```

So considering I was deleting the session vars on `woocommerce_order_status_complete`, they were of course not accessible for the email templates. Changing my `email_after_order_table` to use the updated CPT instead of the session vars solved the problem:

```php
public function email_after_order_table($order) {
    $tickets = get_posts(array(
        'post_type' => 'tickets',
        'numberposts' => -1,
        'meta_query'    => array(array(
            'key'           => 'tickets_reservation',
            'value'         => $order->id
        ))
    ));
    if($tickets) {
        $output = '';
        foreach($tickets as $ticket) {
            $room = strip_tags(get_the_term_list($ticket->ID, 'product_tag'));
            $output .= $ticket->post_title . ' (' . $room . ')<br />';
        }
        if(!empty($output)) {
            echo '<h4>' . __('Tickets', 'my-context') . '</h4><p>' . $output . '</p>';
        }
    }
}
```

The reason why I failed to query the CPT before was pretty trivial: I used `$order->ID` instead of `$order->id`...

I would have like if Woocommerce provided more info about the hooks execution order.